puppeteer Browser Not Getting Launch On Docker With Base Image 16-Buster
Trying To Use This Dockerfile
# Use an official Node.js image as the base
FROM node:16-buster

# Install necessary dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ca-certificates \
    chromium \
    fonts-liberation \
    libasound2 \
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libc6 \
    libcairo2 \
    libcups2 \
    libdbus-1-3 \
    libexpat1 \
    libfontconfig1 \
    libgbm1 \
    libgcc1 \
    libglib2.0-0 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libnspr4 \
    libnss3 \
    libpango-1.0-0 \
    libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
    libstdc++6 \
    libx11-6 \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libxcb1 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxcursor1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxext6 \
    libxfixes3 \
    libxi6 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libxrender1 \
    libxss1 \
    libxtst6 \
    lsb-release \
    wget \
    xdg-utils \
    libvulkan1 \
    && apt-get clean

# Install Puppeteer browser dependencies and cache path
RUN mkdir -p /root/.cache/puppeteer && chmod -R 777 /root/.cache

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /src

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to /src directory
COPY package*.json /src/

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Install Puppeteer's expected Chrome version
RUN npx puppeteer browsers install chrome@131.0.6778.69

# Verify the installed Chrome version
RUN ls -la /root/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/

# Set the PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH environment variable
ENV PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/root/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-131.0.6778.69/chrome-linux64/chrome

# Copy the rest of the application files
COPY . /src

# Compile TypeScript to JavaScript
RUN npm run build

# Expose the port for the application
EXPOSE 5001

# Start the application
CMD ["node", "dist/index.js"]

And this Is the Code : Node - Express Rest Api Route Controller
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer-extra';
import StealthPlugin from 'puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth';
// Set up plugins
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

interface Product {
    name: string | null;
    price: number | null;
    imageUrl: string | null;
    link: string | null;
    reviews: string | null;
}

interface SearchResult {
    searchTerm: string;
    data: Product[];
}

interface ScrapeResult {
    success: boolean;
    data?: SearchResult[];
    error?: string;
}

interface SearchItem {
    searchTerm: string;
    productLimit: number;
    productPage: number;
}

export async function scrapeProducts(
    searchTerms: SearchItem[],
    isBudgetValuePresent: boolean,
    maxBudgetValue: number = -1,
    minBudgetValue: number = -1
): Promise<ScrapeResult> {
    console.log('Using Chrome at:', puppeteer.executablePath());
// also tried executionPath()  + also tried hardcoded docker file path with following
// path 1 : /root/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-131.0.6778.69/chrome-linux64/chrome my-puppeteer-app
// path 2 : // path 1 : /root/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-131.0.6778.85/chrome-linux64/chrome my-puppeteer-app

**    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false, // Run in headless mode
        args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'], // Required for Docker
    });**
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768 });
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);

    page.on('request', (request) => {
        const resourceType = request.resourceType();
        if (resourceType === 'font' || resourceType === 'stylesheet') {
            request.abort();
        } else {
            request.continue();
        }
    });

    const allResults: SearchResult[] = [];
    const maxRetries = 4;

    try {
        for (const term of searchTerms) {
            const encodedTerm = encodeURIComponent(term.searchTerm);
            const url = `https://www.bunnings.com.au/search/products?page=${term.productPage}&q=${encodedTerm}`;

            for (let attempt = 1; attempt <= maxRetries; attempt++) {
                try {
                    console.log(`Navigating to: ${url} (Attempt ${attempt})`);
                    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });

                    // Wait for product tiles to load
                    await page.waitForSelector('.search-product-tile', { timeout: 20000 });
                    console.log(`Successfully loaded search results for "${term.searchTerm}"`);

                    const products: Product[] = await page.evaluate(() => {
                        const items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.search-product-tile'));
                        return items.map(item => {
                            const priceText = (item.querySelector('.sc-bbcf7fe4-3') as HTMLElement)?.innerText || null;
                            const price = priceText ? parseFloat(priceText.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g, "")) : null;
                            return {
                                name: (item.querySelector('.product-title') as HTMLElement)?.innerText || null,
                                price,
                                imageUrl: (item.querySelector('img.search-product-image') as HTMLImageElement)?.src || null,
                                link: item.querySelector('a')?.href || null,
                                reviews: (item.querySelector('.span-review-container') as HTMLElement)?.innerText || null,
                            };
                        });
                    });

                    console.log(`Extracted ${products.length} products for "${term.searchTerm}"`);

                    const productFiltered = products.filter(product =>
                        product.name !== null &&
                        product.price !== null &&
                        product.imageUrl !== null &&
                        product.link !== null &&
                        product.reviews !== null
                    );

                    console.log(`Filtered down to ${productFiltered.length} valid products for "${term.searchTerm}"`);

                    const filteredProducts = isBudgetValuePresent
                        ? productFiltered.filter(product =>
                            product.price !== null &&
                            product.price >= minBudgetValue &&
                            product.price <= maxBudgetValue
                        )
                        : productFiltered;

                    console.log(`Filtered by budget to ${filteredProducts.length} products for "${term.searchTerm}"`);

                    const limitedProducts = filteredProducts.slice(0, term.productLimit);

                    allResults.push({
                        searchTerm: term.searchTerm,
                        data: limitedProducts,
                    });

                    console.log(`Found ${limitedProducts.length} valid products for "${term.searchTerm}".`);
                    break; // Exit retry loop on success

                } catch (error: any) {
                    console.error(`Attempt ${attempt} failed: ${error.message}`);
                    if (attempt === maxRetries) {
                        console.error('Max retries reached. Moving to next term.');
                        throw error;
                    }
                    await page.reload({ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' });
                    console.log('Page reloaded, retrying...');
                }
            }
        }

        return { success: true, data: allResults };

    } catch (error: any) {
        console.error('An error occurred:', error);
        return { success: false, error: error.message };
    } finally {
        await browser.close();
        console.log('Browser closed');
    }
}

you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. npx puppeteer browsers install chrome) or
your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /root/.cache/puppeteer). For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration. Error: Could not find Chrome (ver. **131.0.6778.69**). This can occur if either
you did not perform an installation before running the script (e.g. npx puppeteer browsers install chrome) or
your cache path is incorrectly configured (which is: /root/.cache/puppeteer). For (2), check out our guide on configuring puppeteer at https://pptr.dev/guides/configuration. at ChromeLauncher.resolveExecutablePath (/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserLauncher.js:292:27)
at ChromeLauncher.executablePath (/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:210:25) at ChromeLauncher.computeLaunchArguments (/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:91:37)
at ChromeLauncher.launch (/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserLauncher.js:71:39) at ChromeLauncher.launch (/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/ChromeLauncher.js:45:22) at PuppeteerNode.launch (/src/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/PuppeteerNode.js:132:31) at PuppeteerExtra.launch (/src/node_modules/puppeteer-extra/dist/index.cjs.js:128:41) at async scrapeProducts (file:///src/dist/services/puppeteer.services.js:6:21) 

I have Tried To Check The Other Solutions
I have checked that my Docker Container Have The Chrome Version
Docker File Structure 
so i have tried to download specific version of chrome puppeteer is tried to look for i have also used executionPath() function but it dont work on docker container while it work without docker

my question is if i have browser then why it dont use linux-131.0.6778.85 version

i have also tried to install specifically requested browser but it is not being downloaded in that folder after running the file i still get the above mentioned file structure


I want to run the headless false or headless shell browser in docker container and i want to deploy it in AWS service.

do i need to make any further change to run this same docker file in AWS
why browser is not getting launched even if i have installed all the dependencies and the browser.
why browser is not getting installed even if i specified the version


node node_modules/puppeteer/install.ts,try this form comand line.
